Flutter Text how to remove right side empty space

As you can see, there is am empty space on the Text right side, how can i remove it.
Use CustomPainter can solve this problem but I need to calculate text width first.
Is there another way to remove this empty space?
example code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Flexible(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                 child: Text(
                  "TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)
                )
              )
            )
          ],
        )
      )
      )
    );
  }
}

dartPad: https://dartpad.dev

Just add textAlign:TextAlign.center
Text("TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT",
                   textAlign:TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)
                )


You can't remove this space because text is automatically adjust according to mobile screen.
You cant align text center using text align property.
updated code
Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Flexible(
                  child: Container(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      child: const Text(
                          "TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                        textAlign:TextAlign.center,
                      )
                  )
              )
            ],
          )
      )
  )

